# BreadCrumb- ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We have developed web application, which is purely asp.net MVC3 and C#. We want to implement Breadcrumb navigation link  so that users can click on the breadcrumb to get to any View.

Could any one tell us or point in right direction , how we can implement this? steps would be more helpful.

Thank you

Comment: `to get to any View`. Could you be a little more specific? Also providing a little more context, explaining what your application does, how are your controllers and actions organized would be helpful.

Comment: The way you phrase it sounds more like a sitemap than breadcrumb navigation.. Is that what you need ? (*sitemap*)

Comment: @Darin: We are using application for recording Absences. We have main menu , there are various buttons on the main menu. Every button is linked to a controller and a View. Click on the button will display a form where user can input data. click on some other button will display data in webgrid. Clicking on the hyperlink in web grid will open up a new view via Controller. So there are many stages for recording any event. There is no back button available in the views, only user has to depend on the browser back button. Instead of doing this we want to place a breadcrumb so that it will be good

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [MVC Sitemap provider](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) to give you this functionality. It's available via NuGet too.